# Medical expenses tax deductions - billed vs. paid

Tags: united-states, taxes, tax-deduction, healthcare

In the USA, total medical expenses above a threshold may be deducted from taxes. If a medical expense occurs in December and the bill is paid in January, for tax purposes, does this expense occur in the December year or the next (January) year?

Comment: And right now the floor is changing: it is 7.5% for 2018, but 10% starting in 2019 (except for 65+). But with the TCJA-increased standard deduction, fewer people (perhaps many fewer) will get any benefit from itemizing.

Comment: @dave_thompson _085 Are you sure about the 7.5% floor in 2019 for people over 65?  My Google search said the floor is going to 10% for everybody.

Comment: @ab2: you're right. The new pub 502 isn't out (and the 2017 one was 'printed' while TCJA was still under consideration) so I just assumed it would go back to 2016 rules, but on checking [the nearly-official source](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/26/213) (see (f) at the end) it does go 'back' to 10% for everybody. Down with the geezers!

Answer (score 7):

The expense occurs when you pay it, so the expense would be deductable for the year of that January. (Source: working with a tax accountant last year when I was in a similar situation.  Disclaimer: I am not an accountant.)

Additional source, [IRS pub 502](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/p502.pdf), at the end of page 2:

> You can include only the medical and dental expenses
>   you paid this year, regardless of when the services were
>   provided.